# latex: indents in the equation (boxes instead of digit)

Tags: latex, alignment, vertical-alignment, digits, text-alignment

I want to do the task - addition to the column with unknown digits.

How to make everything so that it is aligned in the center of the boxes and digits?

To digits were under the digits, boxes under the digits, digits under the boxes?

```
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{gX}}}


\begin{multline*}
\begin{array}{r}
+
\begin{array}{r}
\msquare64\msquare\msquare\msquare\\
661977\\
\end{array}\\
\hline
\begin{array}{r}
1\msquare\msquare631\msquare
\end{array}\\
\end{array}
\end{multline*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with an array. As your values are just squares or number, it is better to use the tabular environment where intercolumn spacing can be more finely controlled. To do that, the simpler is to redefine the `tabcolsep` length, but there packages like array that can provide other means to control it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
% \def\msquare{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{gX}}} % redifined, because I do know what \Box does.
\def\msquare{\raisebox{1mm}{\framebox[2mm][r]{}}}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5pt}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{array}{r}
    +
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
      &\msquare&6&4&\msquare&\msquare&\msquare\\
      &6&6&1&9&7&7\\
      \hline
      1&\msquare&\msquare&6&3&1&\msquare
    \end{tabular}\\
  \end{array}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To avoid the redefinition of `tabcolsep` in all your document, enclose this code in braces.

Comment: Alain, it's cool! One question: how set height to framebox (in your example box is small :()

Comment: You can add in the content of framebox a 0 width rule. If you want 1 cm height, change \msquare with `\def\msquare{\raisebox{1mm}{\framebox[2mm][r]{\rule{0pt}{1cm}}}}`. Note that the first parameter controls box vertical position (1mm) and the second box width (2mm). You can change it to fit your needs.